# How to publish MySQL data in text view in android

Tags: mysql, textview

Hii I have multiple text fields in the MySQL database and now I want to display all those texts in the text views I want in my activity could any one provide me any kind of example ,it would be helpful thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create some RESTful web services in order to be able to fetch data from your Android application. Look at this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/) for creating your web service that will be fetching the needed data from your MySQL database. Then from your Android application you should do a HTTP requests to the web service to obtain the needed data. You can see how to do it in the following [example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want something like that suppose I have set name:john in my json here name is key and john is value so how to get that name john in my text view android thanks

Comment: For JSON manipulation, use the [JSON API](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html). You can parse a JSON string into a JSON object/array. Then you should use [findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) in order to get the TextView by providing the ID of your target TextView. This method returns a View (that all views are derived from) so you need to cast that into TextView and then use the method [setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: Could you please provide me any example as I am at very beginning level so it's pretty hard to understand like this one example or piece of code will be more than enough bro thanks

Comment: Actually I have data in the MySQL database and now I just want to get that data and publish in my textview of android pls reply @cricket_007

Comment: Take a look at this TextView [example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/android/textview.html) and this [HttpUrlConnection example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) for requesting data from a web-service. As I explained you need to create a webservice to get data from your MySQL database since the JDBC MySQL driver might not be working for Android.

Comment: I have created json for this

Comment: Now I have my URL available what I don't know is to get that data in my textview of android thanks

Comment: Nice to know I've helped you a little :-)